# How can I rotate the QBitmap nicely while still drawing the position accurately?

Tags: qt, draw, qpixmap

I want to draw a `QBitmap` over an arbitrary point.

For example, I want to draw a `point (5, 5)` on the `QBitmap` to match a `point (10,10)` on the screen.

I also want to change the angle of the `QBitmap` around that point, but if I rotate it, the drawing will be out of position.

How can I rotate the `QBitmap` nicely while still drawing the position accurately?

```
bool MyApp::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
   QBitmap qBmp = QBitmap(".\\pix1.bmp");
   
   int iPixX = 10;
   int iPixY = 10;
   
   int iDrawPointX = 5;
   int iDrawPointY = 5;
   
   if( event->type() == QEvent::Paint ) {
        QPainter painter(m_pUi->drawLayer);

        painter.setPen( QPen(Qt::black) );
        painter.translate(iPixX, iPixY);        
        painter.rotate(45);
        painter.translate(iPixX - iDrawPointX, iPixY - iDrawPointX);

        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, qBmp);
    }

    painter.end();
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
 }
```

Comment: I noticed you're doing the UI in what seems to be Qt/C++. Is there any QML in your code?

Comment: No, there is no QML.

Comment: Could you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'm thinking it would help a lot with figuring out the issue.

Comment: Added code to be drawn. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make translation to position your bitmap in screen coordinates:

```
painter.translate(iPixX - iDrawPointX,iPixY - iDrawPointY);
```

Make translation to position the bitmap in the point which is the origin of rotation operation (this is your missed step, (5,5) coord of bitmap will be rotation origin point):

```
painter.translate(-iPixX, -iPixY);
```

Make rotation:

```
painter.rotate(45);
```

Back to screen coordinates position:

```
painter.translate(iPixX, iPixY);
```

The full code:

```
    painter.translate(iPixX, iPixY);        
    painter.rotate(45);
    painter.translate(-iPixX, -iPixY);
    painter.translate(iPixX - iDrawPointX,iPixY - iDrawPointY);
```

Comment: It appears to be working properly. Thank you.